Добавить обработчик когда пользователь использует "открыть с помощью" electron.js
Хочу сделать чтобы когда пользователь в проводнике или где-то еще пытался открыть файл с помощью моего приложения выполнялся какой-то код. Я уверен что это возможно (так как реализовано в vs code), просто не могу найти как

Чтобы получить путь к файлу, который был перетянут на исполняемый файл ("открыть с помощью" работает так же), мы можем воспользоваться process.argv.
Если не ошибаюсь, то process.argv[1] будет содержать сам путь (это можно или нужно делать в app.whenReady()).
Для MacOS нужно будет отслеживать open-file event и open-url event
